# How to find out what mach_msg_trap waits for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, performance, instruments

I a profiling my iPhone application on target, and according to Instruments 65% of the time is spent in `mach_msg_trap`.

I have a background thread that runs-forever and send results back to the main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, aproximately every 2 seconds. I am not waiting until done.

Comment: So how do you discover what mach_msg_trap is waiting for?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turn out my app is not actually spending 65% of it's time in the `mach_msg_trap` function. It was a configuration error in Instruments on my part.

The Sampler tool defaults to *All Sample Counts*, this will measure all threads regardless of their state.

Instead switch to *Running Sample Times* that will reflect the current actual workload.
[Screenshot of Instruments http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa2009/images/qa1619_running_sample_times.png](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa2009/images/qa1619_running_sample_times.png)

Comment: all the links are broken here

Answer (score 2):

If you're not expecting your main thread to be doing anything other than waiting on this background thread (or waiting for user input) there's nothing to be concerned about -- your application simply has nothing to do most of the time.

If you're expecting the main thread to be actively doing something else, please update your question to describe that. In this case, you might want to look at the full call stacks to mach_msg_trap as it's often at the bottom of a call stack where the actual time-waster is further up.

Comment: I do not expect my main thread to do much except receive the update and redraw the screen once every 2 seconds. I do however expect my background thread to take every last clock cycle left over.

Comment: I still think it may be worth it to check out the callstack above mach_msg_trap just to double check your assumption about that the main thread should just be idling.